# Hamiltonian paths in cubic graphs with cyclically edge connectivity at least 5

Tags: graph-theory, hamiltonian-path

> **Definitions** A *cubic* graph (simple) $G$ is a 3-regular graph.  An edge cut $K$ is *cycle separating* if $G-K$ is disconnected and at least two components of $G-K$ have circuits.  A graph is *cyclically edge-$k$-connected* if no set of fewer than $k$ edges is cycle separating.  The *cyclical edge connectivity* of $G$ is the largest integer $k$ such that the graph is cyclically edge-$k$-connected.

Our question is the following:

> **Question** Would anybody know any examples of cubic graphs which have cyclically edge connectivity at least 5 which do not have Hamiltonian paths (not cycles)?  If there is such an example and it is edge-3-colorable, would you know of an example which is not edge-3-colorable?

Comment: House of Graphs has a [lot of data on cubic graphs](https://hog.grinvin.org/Cubic). You can try to look for required examples there.

Comment: @AlexRavsky Thank you! I already tested most of those ... I am expecting that in the remaining few that I haven’t tested I won’t find counterexamples.  There is a conjecture (Thomassen) that there is a constant k such that all cyclically edge-k-connected graphs Hamiltonian, and it is thought k might be 8 (it would be best possible).  So surely an analogue might hold for Hamilton paths.  And so I was wondering whether a construction might be known that I am not aware of.  I need to edit the question to say cyclic edge connectivity at least 5.  Thanks!

Comment: @AlexRavsky By the way, I tested only the ones that are labeled (somewhere else in the website you sent) as cyclically edge-5-connected ...